# why open command doesn't allow me to open and read the file withou using 'with' command?

Tags: python-3.x, with-statement

I'm a beginner of Python code and went through some related questions 
explaining about differences between 'with' and 'with open' command.

But because of my lack of knowledge on Python 3, I still don't get the difference between the two and couldn't figure out how to make my code run.

In the tutorial I am studying now, the answer is as below.

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=[]
y=[]
with open('example.txt', 'r') as csvfile:
    plot = csv.reader (csvfile, delimiter = ',')
    for row in plots:
        x.append(int(row[0]))
        y.append(int(row[1]))

plt.plot(x,y,label='file')
plt.show()
```

What I tried to do was using open and csv.reader command like below

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plotdata = open ('testing.csv') 
reader = csv.reader(plotdata, delimiter =',')
hx=[ ]
hy=[ ]
for x in reader:
    hx.append(reader[0])
    hy.append(reader[1])
plt.plot(hx, hy)
```

While the first one with "with" command works, the below one without "with" command doesn't work. Just in case I added `close()` command at the end but keep showing the error message 
"TypeError: '_csv.reader' object is not subscriptable"

What was wrong?

Answer (score 0):

My ideas are the following:

a) always use `with` in file operations

b) except for excercises separate you reading of data and manipulating of data

c) `plot` (bad name) and `reader` are iterators, in a loop you consume the iterator to obtain `row` or `x`, which are elements provided by iterator. `reader` itself cannnot be adressed by `[0]`, you must have wanted to use `x[0]` and  `x[1]` instead.

Comment: Really appreciate for you tips. I found out what I have been doing wrong and will try that approach for opening files.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that in the second code you are subscribing directly `reader[0]`, otherwise in the first one you are subscribing its iterated value (`row in plots`) converted: `int(row[0])`.

This should work:

```
for x in reader:
    hx.append(int(x[0]))
    hy.append(int(x[1]))
plt.plot(hx, hy)
```

Comment: Really appreciate for you answer. It resolved my 4-hour-long struggling.

Comment: Waiting for @Soonk action